# Windows 7 network share is not accessible, handle invalid, 4672 4634

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, authentication

I have two Windows 7 PCs, no domain, same workgroup.

PC A used to be able to connect to PC B's network shares.
Now it can't. Winf firewall on PC B is off for troubleshooting.

From PC A, double-clicking on PC B name in Explorer's network view prompts a login dialog box.

Login uses `PC B\username` on PC B, with correct password.

Error message is:

```
PC B is not accessible. handle is invalid.
```

Event viewer on PC B `eventvwr winlogs\security` shows the event ids:

```
4672 special logon
```

and immediately after it

```
4634 logoff logon type 3 (network)
```

So it appears PC A is using a valid user account and password to login to PC B, the login is accepted, but then the login is immediately logged off.

Using elevated cmd prompt on PC A, `net view \\PC B` returns

```
System Error 5 has occurred. Access is denied
```

The only thing I can think of that may have triggered this is that PC A was renamed using "Computer Properties" and restarted. The access problem began after this procedure.

Any tips on how to further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Two recent Windows Updates (KB 4480970 and KB 4480960) broke the ability for administrators to access SMB2 shares on several OS versions, including Windows 7. Did you recently install those updates on either A or B? Is the user in question an administrator?

Comment: I've heard an update is causing WIN7 to stop seeing SMB Shares. Please check if any update have been recently installed (manually or though automatic update) in the time this issue start to occur. This `KB4480970` in particular is known for this. More info [here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-kb4480960-and-kb4480970-updates-causing-network-and-license-problems/).

Comment: thanks for the links, i will investigate the proposed solution at https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-releases-kb4487345-update-to-fix-windows-7-share-issues/

Answer (score 0):

Doug and Manuel are right on!  I was having the same issue, plus remote desktop wasn't working.  The fix was https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4487345/update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2.  And yes, my account was administrator on the machines that were failing.

Comment: Please provide your steps in answer how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

had a same issue with win 7. After uninstalling KB 4480970 problem disappeared.
If you can't uninstall KB 4480970 you can get remote desktop running by changing My Computer-->properties-->remote settings--> Remote desktop--> Allow connections from computers running any version of remote desktop.
I have not managed to resolve shares issue without KB uninstall.

Two days later  KB 4480970 got installed again. You have to disable it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as the OP. This problem was new and out of the blue, after having installed recent Windows update updates.

If you follow https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4487345/update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2 as mentioned in @Dave Strandberg's answer, you'll get to a page that describes the problem. It says:

> This update resolves the issue where local users who are part of the local “Administrators“ group may not be able to remotely access shares on Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 machines after installing the January 8th, 2019 security updates. This does not affect domain accounts in the local "Administrators" group.
>
> To get the stand-alone package for this update, go to the Microsoft Update Catalog website.

It offers a link to http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4487345.

I wasn't keen to uninstall updates, so I applied this update and it fixed the problem. The update requires a reboot (at least it did on my machines). Note that you want to apply it to the machine that hosts the share, not the machine trying to access it.